# Styled-Component nao ativa o estilo

Tags: react, typescript, webpack, packages, styled-components

Estou fazendo um clone do Discord, em TSX, usando styled components.
Porem quando crio os styled.ts, percebo pela identacao que o estilo nao foi aplicado.

Meu Json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria estar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa, primeiramente, instalar uma extensão para destacar a sintaxe CSS do styled-components, afinal é apenas uma string dentro do seu arquivo TypeScript.

Instale https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components

Você também se esqueceu de colocar o `;` no final de algumas linhas e colocou comentários `//`, que são inválidos no CSS.

Comment: Obrigada, era exatamente isso que faltava. Com o plug-in pude visualizar todos os bugs do codigo.

Comment: @harriet Caso consiga, marque a resposta do colega como certa.